# Prove that a certain integration yields the value $\frac{7}{9}$

Tags: integration

Numerical methods surely indicate that $\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} 2 \sqrt{9 x+1} \sqrt{21 x-4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1} \left(4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9
   x+1)}+1\right) \, dx= \frac{7}{9}$.

Can this be formally demonstrated?

Answer (score 11):

Yes it can, because the long square root equals $\sqrt{9x+1}-\sqrt{12 x}$. After this observation you get a standard integral, which reduces to an integral of rational function if you change the variable to $\sqrt{9/x+1}$.

Comment: Great! This question arose from a previous posting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327016/can-knowledge-of-int-fx2-dx-possibly-be-used-in-obtaining-int-fx-dx involving three integrations. I presume these three individual problems can be similarly solved--a matter into which I will presently investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pursuing (as best I can) the line of reasoning put forth by K B Dave in his (stereographic-projection-motivated) answer to the related (antecedent) question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327016/can-knowledge-of-int-fx2-dx-possibly-be-used-in-obtaining-int-fx-dx, I make the transformation $x\to \frac{4 m^2}{3 \left(m^2-3\right)^2}$, having a jacobian of $\frac{8 m \left(m^2+3\right)}{3 \left(m^2-3\right)^3}$ and new limits of integration (0,1}, whereupon Mathematica directly yields the desired answer of $\frac{7}{9}$.

K B Dave had written:

Let
\begin{equation}
3 x=u^2, 9 x+1=v^2,
\end{equation}
and stereographically project the curve $v^2-3 u^2=1$ about $(u,v) =(0,1)$, so that
\begin{equation}
\frac{v-1}{u}= \frac{3 u}{v+1}=m.
\end{equation}

Then the integrands reduce to rational expression in $m$.,…